# JComboBox setPopupVisible not called on clicking arrow

Tags: java, swing

When clicking the arrow to open the popup on a JComboBox the overridden setPopupVisible is not called, see minimal example below. Am i just missing something here or doing something wrong? Any hints appreciated :)

The goal here is that i want to control its visibility behaviour, especially only hiding it under certain conditions, for example input checking (mind that the combobox is editable).

Using Java 8.

Building a Frame with a custom JComboBox:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    MyComboBox combo = new MyComboBox();
    combo.setEditable(true);
    combo.addItem("bli");
    combo.addItem("bla");
    combo.addItem("blu");
    combo.addItem("ble");
    frame.add(combo);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

The custom JComboBox:

```
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class MyComboBox extends JComboBox {

@Override
public void setPopupVisible(boolean v) {
    if(!v) {
        System.out.println("HIDING COMBOBOX");
        super.setPopupVisible(v);
    } else {
        System.out.println("SHOWING COMBOBOX");
        super.setPopupVisible(v);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `JComboBox` `setPopupVisible(boolean)` API is NOT there to notify when the popup is opened/closed. It is there to programmatically show the popup or hide the popup.

If you want to be notified when the popup is opened/closed, you can use `addPopupMenuListener()` like in below code:

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;
import java.awt.Frame;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    MyComboBox combo = new MyComboBox();
    combo.setEditable(true);
    combo.addItem("bli");
    combo.addItem("bla");
    combo.addItem("blu");
    combo.addItem("ble");

    combo.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println("Popup Menu Will Become Visible");
      }

      @Override
      public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println("Popup Menu Will Become Invisible");
      }

      @Override
      public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e)
      {
        System.out.println("Popup Menu Canceled");
      }
    });

    frame.add(combo);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class MyComboBox extends JComboBox
{

  @Override
  public void setPopupVisible(boolean v) {
    if(!v) {
      System.out.println("HIDING COMBOBOX");
      super.setPopupVisible(v);
    } else {
      System.out.println("SHOWING COMBOBOX");
      super.setPopupVisible(v);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i probably should've made it clearer: I'm surprised it isn't used by Java itself to show/hide the popup. It would've provided me with a really easy way to control if i want it to be visible or not, but since the arrow ignores the function i cannot do that.

Comment: @wlfbck, It's still a bit unclear. What do you expect `setPopupVisible()` to do? And when do you expect it to be invoked? If you give us an example code you want to have inside overridden `setPopupVisible()`, that may explain your intention.

Comment: Well, i expect Java to use it's own declared methods. i expect setPopupVisible() to do exactly what it says, including it being called when somebody (whether that is some other programmer or Java/Swing) wants to show/hide the popup menu of this ComboBox. Seems quite reasonable tbh.



If i would use the listener the popup would for example always get hidden before i could show it again (if i wanted to do that for some reason).